# Scrollable tablayout with different GridViews

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout

I'm planning on building an Android app with a screen like this:[image]

The first part of the screen contains general information (could be product info, etc). The middle contains of two tabs and the last shows a grid view.
There are two different gridViews, on for each tab. They have different sizes and different content.

The entire screen should be scrollable, not just the gridview, if you scroll anywhere on the screen, the current gridView should scroll, but also the General Information and tabs.

An optional feature could be that if you scroll down quite a bit, so that you don't see the General Information anymore. If you then scroll up only a little bit, the general information would be visible again.

How is this best implemented? I thought about using a tabLayout with PageViewer and a Fragment for each GridView, but I'm not sure how to get everything to scroll correctly, and how to set the size of the PageViewer correct for each of the different GridViews, depending on their amount of content.

What is the best way to implement this functionality?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a **Bottom Sheet**.

In practice you should have a *ConstraintLayout* with widgets that will display your general informations and a *NestedScrollView* with this behavior

`app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"`

In this way you will have a scrollable bottom sheet that can be customized as you prefer.

Take a look at

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've already started looking into the "CollapsingToolBar" and parallax scroll with tabs, from this link:

https://android.jlelse.eu/parallax-scrolling-header-tabs-android-tutorial-2cc6e40aa257

But if it doesn't work out I will give bottom sheets a go, thanks for the help!